# Nested grid alignment

Tags: html, css, css-grid

There is a grid with a dynamic number of elements that fills depending on the height of the parent. Nested elements are also grids to align content vertically. In my example, the red numbers should be under the red ones - the black ones under the black ones, as in the screenshot below. In the code below they are not aligned. How to do it? I know about subgrid, but I need a solution without it

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTw0x.png)

```
  <h1 id="header"></h1>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='grid-item'>
      <div class='grid-item-inner'>
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        <span class="grid-item-inner-offset">109123</span>
      </div>
      <span class="grid-item-inner-offset" style="color:red">1201</span>
    </div>
    <div class='grid-item'>
      <div class='grid-item-inner'>
        <span>Dorem</span>
        <span class="grid-item-inner-offset">1091</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid-item'>
      <div class='grid-item-inner'>
        <span>Amet</span>
        <span class="grid-item-inner-offset">109123</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid-item'>
      <div class='grid-item-inner'>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dorem</span>
        <span class="grid-item-inner-offset">19123</span>
      </div>
     <span class="grid-item-inner-offset" style="color:red">14</span>
    </div>
    <div class='grid-item'>
      <div class='grid-item-inner'>
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        <span class="grid-item-inner-offset">19123</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
body {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 5px 25px;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 19px);
}

.grid-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.grid-item-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid-item-inner-offset {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to restructure your HTML to solve this one.

Comment: Despite your description, I'm still not clear on what this *should* look like, a design image would be useful.

Comment: @Paulie_D [Design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTw0x.png)

Comment: That image does not seem to match your required description. *"the red numbers should be under the red ones - the black ones under the black ones"*

Comment: @Paulie_D [Design image](https://imgur.com/o7ty1t6) The red number may not be present in the cell

Comment: So you should have the cell there regardless even if it's not populated. Frankly this is essentially a `table` and not something `grid` should do.

Comment: @Paulie_D but tables can't do [that](https://imgur.com/prrkHWX)